# Display chinese characters in array

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, odbc

I have an issue with my rails app. I want to display non-ASCII characters (like Chinese) in an array.

When I display the array content, I have this:

```
puts array_table  => ["a","b","\xE6\x80\xBB\xE8\xA1\xA8 Main Report"]
```

The third element is in English + Chinese but displays like you can see.

If I try to display the third element only:

```
PUTS array_table[2] => "总表 Main Report"
```

What I need to run my app is to have my array like this:

```
["a","b","总表 Main Report"]
```

Any idea?

I have windows 2012 server R2 with SQL Azure latest connecting trough ODBC driver with activerecord-sqlserver-adpater 4.2.3, rails 4.1.6 with ruby 2.

Comment: i added this in application.rb file                                                                       config.encoding = "utf-8"                                                                                  and this to environment.rb                                   Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8                                                             but stil not working

Comment: Does the database type is nvarchar()